# Dropdown menu not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a Dropdown menu that shows 2 links, one to my image gallery and other to the video gallery, but when I am in a view except my `index.ctp`, the dropdown doesn´t open at all. If I place `dropdown.js` from the "source code" distribuition and include it in the layout the dropdowns don't work in `index.ctp` but they work on the other views. Also while searching on google I found this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/D6CAiwOZI8w) wich allowed me to use it in all views but the menus only open once, what is the issue with this?

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 and CakePHP 2.4.4

**Layout**

```
      <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Música', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Musica'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Animação Temática', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'AnimacaoTematica'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Promoção', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Promocao'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Staff', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Staff'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Aluguer', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Aluguer'))?></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

**Layout head**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;//titulo dinamico da página?></title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');

    echo $this->Html->script('modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->element('fancybox_links');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.0');
    echo $this->Html->script('main');
    echo $this->element('fancybox_links');
    echo $this->Html->css('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5');
    echo $this->Html->script('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5');        
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('main');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('dropdown');
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".fancybox3").fancybox(e){
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'float'
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            });
    </script> 
    <!--<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
```

Comment: Do you have anything else in home.ctp ?

Comment: I corrected the view name, is index.ctp. On that view i have a slideshow that I am trying to make it work, and simple text.

Comment: please fix js error if it has any

Comment: Related to bootstrap it doesn't have any, but there are many related with fancybox, and one to modernizr it seems, all not found, but the modernizr js file is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having cleaned up the js folder and having reinstalled fancybox from [here](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions) , and then [this](https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin/tree/master/Fancybox) plugin, the dropdowns started working how they should.

**Leyout Head**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;//titulo dinamico da página?></title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->Html->script('modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.0.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('main');
    echo $this->Html->css('main');

    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');

    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('dropdown');
    echo $this->Html->script('collapse');
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".fancybox3").fancybox(e){
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'float'
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            });
    </script> -->
    </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to load `bootstrap` and `jquery` on other pages.

You need to include `bootstrap` and `jquery` in your common file or in header section.

Also check for `confliction` if you used other `framework/library`.

Comment: I have an issue with loading `jquery`, but only related to fancybox. The other `jquery` and `bootstrap` are included.

Comment: All is included on the layout header, it is all there.

Comment: Why you added `bootstrap` twice? You included `bootstrap` and `bootstrap.min` both. Also check in `console` for `errors`.

Comment: I removed the bootstrap.min, and after that none of the dropdowns worked at all.